# Pandas equivalent to sql for month date time

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a pandas dataframe that I need to filter just like a sql query for a specific month.  Everytime I run the code I want it to grab data from the previous month, no matter what the specific day is of the current month.

My SQL code is here but I need pandas equivalent.

`WHERE DATEPART(m, logged) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))`

````
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['1-05-01 00:00:00','1-06-01 00:00:00','1-06-01 00:00:00','1-05-01 00:00:00']})
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])```

In this example, I only want the data from June. 
Would definitely appreciate the help!  Thanks.
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: [Here are the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) on datetime functionality. It would be best if you tried some things and updated your question with your attempts so we could better help you

Comment: how do you display a pandas dataframe in your question on stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying based on the question edit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['1-05-01 00:00:00','1-06-01 00:00:00','1-06-01 00:00:00','1-05-01 00:00:00']})
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])  

## To get it to the right format
import datetime as dt
df['month'] = df['month'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%d-%m'))
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])  

## Extract the month from this date
df['month_ex'] = df.month.dt.month

## Get current month to get the latest month from the dataframe, which is the previous month of the current month
from datetime import datetime
currentMonth = datetime.now().month

newDf = df[df.month_ex == currentMonth - 1]
```

Output:

```
       month  month_ex
1 2001-06-01         6
2 2001-06-01         6
```

Comment: what part of this will only extract last months data based on the current month?  That is all I need.

Comment: What you mean by last month's data? The second line does current date - 1 month, the fourth line goes to the first date of the previous month.

Comment: If I ran this code right now in the month of July, what would give me only June's data?  The data set I am working with only has two months.  May and June, for example, and I only want the data with the time stamp of June.

Comment: "If I ran this code right now in the month of July, what would give me only June's data?" - It is getting harder to interpret what you exactly want. Please add sample input and output example perhaps.

Comment: "I only want the data with the time stamp of June." - assuming you have a column for dates with July, the 2nd and the 4th line like I said should give you dates for June.

Comment: just revised the question.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: I was thinking something like a loc to extract previous month.  I am not wanting to actually change the dates, only filter the dates for the last month based on the current month.

Comment: Just changed it, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks!  Are you running that exact code above?  It is giving me an empty dataframe for some reason.

Comment: There was one line missing, could you please check now?

Comment: perfect!   Thanks for the help!